# Page stops displaying

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I'm trying to code a basic messaging system for my website. I have the sending and reciving set up, but for some reason on the inbox the html just stops displaying. It displays halfway through the page and then just stops for some reason. Won't even display basic html like if I typed

Hello

it wouldn't show up. I'm confused as this has never happened before.

```
        </table> 
<p>Hello</p><!--THIS WILL DISPLAY-->
<?php
///////////End take away///////////////////////
// SQL to gather their entire PM list
include_once ('../../mysql_server/connect_to_mysql.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messaging WHERE to_id='$my_id' AND    recipientDelete='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

$date = strftime("%b %d, %Y",strtotime($row['time_sent']));
if($row['opened'] == "0"){
        $textWeight = 'msgDefault';
} else {
        $textWeight = 'msgRead';
}
$fr_id = $row['from_id'];    
// SQL - Collect username for sender inside loop
$ret = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMembers WHERE id='$fr_id' LIMIT 1");
while($raw = mysql_fetch_array($ret)){ $Sid = $raw['id']; $Sname = $raw['firstname']; }

?> 
<p>Hello</p><!--THIS WON'T DISPLAY-->
    <table width="96%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4">
```

Any help is appreciated..

EDIT:

The first while loop does close, just after the table. Everything outside the first while loop displays, however, everything inside the while loop doesn't.

Comment: You probably have an error in your PHP somewhere, are there any errors (are they enabled?)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is just a cut and paste error, but your first while loop doesn't look closed. Try closing it and see where it goes from there.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ //needs closing
```

EDIT: 
Have you tried to see if your sql is throwing any errors:

```
// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$sql) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
```

This PHP [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) might be useful.